# Java KeyEvent - why "Unknown" != "Unknown"?

Tags: java, string, substring, keyevent

Why does

```
KeyEvent.getKeyText(0).substring(0, 7) == "Unknown"
```

return false when

```
System.out.print(KeyEvent.getKeyText(0).substring(0, 7));
```

prints exactly "Unknown"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java Strings are objects, so you should not compare with `==`. You have to call equals on strings to compare there content. 
If you compare them with `==` you compare them by reference.

```
KeyEvent.getKeyText(0).substring(0, 7).equals("Unknown");
```

An alternative would be contains:

```
KeyEvent.getKeyText(0).contains("Unknown");
```

See this post: [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

Comment: You *can* compare with `==`, but it compares the references, that's all.